# Authenticate chrome extension using Facebook

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension

My extension needs to periodically send some data (in the background) to the the server with auth information about the user from FB. So I obvisouly need to send FB token with the data.

Right now I am opening `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<APP_ID>&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` in a new tab, then retrivieng a token from a hash (using background page), then storing it in localStorage.

But lets say user closes his browser and opens it after the token expires. How should I retrieve a new one without user doing lots of additional clicks?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you should [request long-lived token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/) via your server and store that along with the calculated time of expiration that you can get from [token debug API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/) in the local storage. Then you refresh the token before it expires to avoid re-authentication.